# PCRE Capture same letter X instnaces

Tags: regex, pcre

Suppose I have the following possible inputs:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
...
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
...
99999999999999999999999
```

I'd like to write simple PCRE that verifies whether we are facing this case, ie sequences of a given character **'X'** times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say X = 10.

If you know the character, it's simple. for instance, for `A:`

```
A{10}
```

If you want to match *any* character *X* times, the regex will be:

```
(.)\1{9}
```

Explanation: match a character, then try to match the same one 9 more times.

If you want *at least X times*, use this variant:

```
(.)\1{9,}
```

If you just want to validate the whole input is a sequence of the same character, this will do:

```
^(.)\1*$
```

Or this, if you additionally want to validate the length:

```
^(.)\1{9}$
```

Comment: You're assuming we know in advance how long the lines should be. The OP doesn't say that. (The OP also doesn't say we *don't*.)

Comment: Well, apparently we know in advance how long the lines are. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my last example doesn't assume that. I didn't really understand which particular case the OP needs so I just wrote a bunch of them ;)

Comment: The (formerly) last example also doesn't do what I'm pretty sure the question requires: Ensure that the lines are of equal length.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in my understanding, OP means each line is a different example input (he says *inputs* in the question).

Comment: Could you add explanations also to the last two expressions like you did for the first (just for educational purposes)?

Comment: @Trilarion This is basic regex syntax so I didn't explain it... But basically `^` is an anchor that only matches at the start of the string and `$` is an anchor that only matches at the end. OTher than that the regex inside is the same. Oh, and `*` means *zero or more times*.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it's basic syntax but with regex I always get confused how you can assemble basix syntax into complex expressions. Here I learned something.

Comment: @Trilarion HTH. If you want, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3764814)'s a regex FAQ that may be helpful (and the first advice about the book is really good).